# How to add custom taxonomy to search

Tags: custom-taxonomy, search, pre-get-posts

So I have custom taxonomy called "cars". I would want that when user does search, it would also search through taxonomy. Meaning that in "cars" taxonomy if I have "Audi" term and user search with keyword "audi" it would then return posts that are tagged with term "audi".

I tried this:

```
function mytheme_pre_get_posts( $query ) {
$query->set( 'tax_query', array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'cars',
            'field'    => 'name',
            'terms'    =>  $_GET['s'],
        )
    ));
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'mytheme_pre_get_posts', 1 );
```

But that breaks the search completely. Can this be done even or did I miss something?

Comment: Also note that you're modyfing all WP_Query calls on your site with this code snippet, so I think you want to restrict it to the main search query in the front-end?

Answer (score 2):

You could try unsetting the original search query, otherwise you may be doubling up and the combination results in nothing? eg, try adding to your function:

```
$query->set('s','');
```

**UPDATE**

I am not sure on this one, but you could try the `AND` operator -I *think* this adds to the existing query instead of replacing it...

```
function mytheme_pre_get_posts( $query ) {
    if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_search() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $term = get_term_by('name', get_query_var('s'), 'cars');
        if ($term) {
            $query->set( 'tax_query', array(
                 array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'cars',
                    'field'    => 'slug',
                    'terms'    =>  $term->slug,
                    'operator' => 'AND'
                )
            ));
         }
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'mytheme_pre_get_posts', 1 );
```

Note: changed use of field `name` as mentioned by @PieterGoosen to `slug`, and pre-fetched term slug to pass to tax query, and extra conditions as mentioned by @birgire.

Comment: But does normal keyword search still work? Maybe I missed from my original post, that the normal keyword (for example title) should still work. Searching from taxonomy is just addition to the default search. EDIT. I tried and doesn't help. This will loose the searched keyword from field too.

Comment: yeah I thought you wanted to replace the existing search... another suggestion in the update.

Comment: You do not want to use the `name` value `field` in your `tax_query`. There is a known "bug" in the `WP_Tax_Query` class that completely stuffs up term names which causes an epic failure and leads to the `JOIN` clause never being added to the SQL query

Comment: good to know, have updated the code to use slug... hopefully slugs, being molluscs, are bug free. ;-)

Comment: ps: this will change all WP_Query calls on the site when the s GET parameter is a term,, so we should restrict this further?

Comment: @birgire added an extra `is_search` condition, that should suffice?

Comment: I think we need to be more restrict because `is_search()` can be true for all secondary queries as well, since this is only a check for the global `$wp_query` main query. I would try `$query->is_main_query()` and also `&query->is_search()` and then perhaps `! is_admin()` for the front-end only?

Comment: ok yeah why not... :-)

Comment: It looks better, because now I think we don't get a PHP notice if `$_GET['s']` isn't  set. We also don't need all these extra (). We might also consider using  `$query->get('s')` to get the search query variable from the secondary query or `get_query_var( 's' )` or even the escaped `get_search_query()` since we target the main search query ?